# How to select different dropdowns which has same name in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

[image: This select fields has same name]

Error showing as

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select
```

Here is my code:

```
List<WebElement> ref = driver.findElements(By.name("customerBean.relationCd"));
System.out.println("reference dropdowns " + ref.size());
((Select) ref.get(0)).selectByIndex(18);
((Select) ref.get(1)).selectByIndex(18);
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML of the page you're using?  There might be something distinguishing between these two that could help us find a unique selector that's better than just the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you have type-casted WebElement object to the Select object.

```
((Select) ref.get(0)).selectByIndex(18);
```

That is not how it can be done. The Select object should be used separately as defined with webelement as parameter and not by type casting.

```
List<WebElement> ref = driver.findElements(By.name("customerBean.relationCd"));
System.out.println("reference dropdowns " + ref.size());
Select s;

s = new Select(ref.get(0));
s.selectByIndex(18);

s = new Select(ref.get(1));
s.selectByIndex(18);
```

Hope that helps you, let me know if you have more query.